# Eclipse Android APK Export

Tags: android, eclipse, export, apk

I modified a template for an Icon Pack for Android. Now I want to know if it works and so I tried to export my Project to an APK. But when I try to export the APK it says "sun/misc/BASE64Encoder". How can I fix that problem?

Comment: That class is not in recent versions of Java. In any case Eclipse hasn't been supported for Android development for a long time now.

Comment: Do you know how I make an Icon PAck with android studio?